# Express - Session mismatch, user ends up on other user

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, redis

Have a major probelm that usser sometimed ends up on wrong user.

Have the following setup in app.js.

```
    var session = require('express-session');
    var RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);
    var redis = require('redis');
    var app = express();
    env.express(app);
    app.enable('trust proxy');
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
    app.use(methodOverride());
    app.use(cookieParser());
    app.use(session({
        secret : config.envConfig.session.secret,
        name : config.envConfig.session.name,
        store: new RedisStore({
            host: config.envConfig.redis.host,
            port: config.envConfig.redis.port,
            client: redis.createClient(),
            ttl: config.envConfig.redis.sessionTimout
})
```

Node application has a nginx reverse proxy on front.
Any ideas, please!!!
(Mabye it has something todo with   app.enable('trust proxy'))

Here is where i load the layout, userData.

```
exports.loadPage = function(req, res){
        var pageId = req.params.pageId;
        var serverId = req.session.server;
        var user = req.session.user;
        var body = {
            "pages": ""
        };

        projectsService.getAsdf(serverId, user.Token)
            .then(function(aa) {
                return pagesService.loadPage(pageId, aa);
            })
            .then(function(pages){
                body.pages = pages;
                return subscriptionService.getSsss({server:serverId, system:user.Guid, id:user.userId,
                    type: "user"})
                    .then(function (sub) {
                        res.send(200, body);
                    })
                    .catch(function () {
                        res.send(200, body);
                    });
            })
            .catch(function(err) {
                log.error(err);
                res.send(500, "Could not load the page");
            });
    };

    exports.loadUserData = function(req, res){
        var user = req.session.user,
            guid = req.session.user.GUID,
            serverId = req.session.server;

        userData.getUserData(user.userId, guid)
            .then(function(result){
                var deferred = q.defer();
                var serverData;
                var groupsData;
                serverService.getSettings(serverId)
                    .then(function(server){
                        serverData = server;
                        return someService.getGroups(server.apiUrl, user.Token);
                    })
                    .then(function(groups){
                        groupsData = JSON.parse(groups);
                        return someService.getAllUsers(serverData.apiUrl, user.Token);
                    })
                    .then(function(allAgents){
                        var allAgentsGroup = { "id": -1, "users": JSON.parse(allAgents) };
                        groupsData.unshift(allAgentsGroup);
                        return groupsService.saveGroups(groupsData, systemGuid);
                    })
                    .then(function(){
                        result.asdf = serverData.asdf;
                        return deferred.resolve(result);
                    })
                    .catch(function(err){
                        return deferred.reject(err);
                    })
                    .done();
                return deferred.promise;
            })
            .then(function(result){
                result.serverTime = new Date();
                result.instanceId = new ObjectID();
                res.send(200, result);
            })
            .catch(function(err){
                res.send(err.statusCode || 500, "Could not initialize the user data.");
            });
        };
```

//login-method we i set the session...

```
    exports.login = function (req, res) {
        var credentials = req.body.user;
        credentials.isSuperUser = credentials.username.endsWith("****"); 

        authService.authenticate(credentials)
            .then(loginSuccess)
            .catch(loginError)
            .done();

        function loginSuccess(authenticatedResults){
            if (credentials.isSuperUser && authenticatedResults.length > 1 && credentials.server && credentials.version){
                authenticatedResults = authenticatedResults.filter(function (item) {
                    return item.server === credentials.server && item.version === credentials.version;
                });
            }

            if(authenticatedResults.length === 1){
                req.session.user = authenticatedResults[0].user;
                req.session.server = authenticatedResults[0].server;
                req.session.version = authenticatedResults[0].version;
                logger.userLoggedIn(req.session.user); 
            }

            res.send(200, authenticatedResults);
        }
```

//Nginx looks something like this

```
        server {    
         listen 80;
         server_name domain.com;
         proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
         proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
         proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500;
         proxy_connect_timeout   2;
         proxy_set_header Host $host;
         proxy_http_version 1.1;

          location /user/ {
            add_header Set-Cookie "version='';Path=/";
            rewrite ^/user(.*)$ http://$server_name:80? redirect;   
           }

           location / {
            proxy_pass http://$sticky_backend;
          }
            location ~ ^/(?<cver>v[12])/ {
            add_header Set-Cookie "version=$cver;Path=/";
            rewrite ^/v[12]/(.*)$ /$1 redirect;
          }
    }
```

**Edit:**
My problem was on IIS - wich was in front of Nginx. Solved by disable cache and kernel cache on iis.

Comment: Both users are using different browsers (or are working from different computers)? Can you reproduce without nginx in front of Node? What is `env.express(app)`?

Comment: It's totally different users that has nothing to do with each other. Diffrent location, computer, browsers.
That's the problem is really hard reproduce it.
Like on 1 in 100 login maybe more.So tits hadr to verify if there has any effect without nginx.

http://expressjs.com/guide/behind-proxies.html

Comment: Can you show the code there you're using the session data? These kinds of issues can happen if you don't use proper variable scoping, for instance.

Comment: Updated org-post with some code.

Comment: If misconfigured, Nginx can cache response headers, including `Set-Cookie`. Could you show the `server` block of your Nginx configuration?

Comment: Was there any resolution to this?

Comment: My problem was on IIS - wich was in front of Nginx. Solved by disable cache and kernel cache on iis.